# How to implement a booking system using Drupal Commerce for checkout?

Tags: commerce, bookings

I have been playing with [Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms), [Availability Calendars](https://www.drupal.org/project/availability_calendars), commerce availability, and many other modules to achieve my goal but I have had no luck in trying to achieve exactly what I want to do.

Does anyone know of the best solution to achieve the following:

- A holiday home booking system where users can search node teasers via available dates and checkout via [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).
- Views integration: Search nodes on available dates
- Checkout: be able to choose a date range from available dates and checkout through [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Easy Booking](https://www.drupal.org/project/easy_booking) distribution, to check if there is anything in it similar to what you're looking for (specific to the way this distribution uses [Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms) and [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)). If you find something, it is just a matter of reusing what's appropriate in your own site, or just use that distribution (attention: it only has a beta release so far).

Here are some more details about this distribution (quotes from its project page):

> ... to set up a website, that will suit all your needs in managing your own hotel, inn or hostel online.
>
> It gives a set of options for visitors to make room reservations, contact hotel administration or just follow hotel’s newsletter to be aware of all special offers and discounts.
>   Easy booking profile is powered by Drupal [Rooms](https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms) and [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) - widely used and popular contributed decisions, which means active maintaining and timely technical support.

**Note**: for some other module suggestions that might possibly help, refer to my answer to the question "https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173341/how-to-create-this-reservation-form-in-drupal/173467#173467".